# How to preserve decimal places in PHP json encode?

Tags: php, json

Have the below code. want to preserve all the decimal places of the latitude but json_encode truncates last two digits.  How can i preserve all the decimal place when i do json_encode. I want the values as numeric in json output and dont want as string enclosed in  quotes.

```
print_r(array('lat' => '-33.661853351608244' ));
echo json_encode( array('lat' => '-33.661853351608244' ),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [lat] => -33.661853351608244
)
{"lat":-33.661853351608}
```

Comment: Floating point doesn't have enough digits of precision to preserve all those decimal places.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with your php version? i ran your code on http://www.writephponline.com/ and it works as expected

Comment: @Amine It may depend on whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit PHP.

Comment: then he might just have to convert them to a string and parse them on reception to wherever he's gonna use the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set precision to desired decimal places

```
ini_set( 'precision', 17 );
$arr = array(
  'lat' =>  "-33.661853351608244"
);

echo json_encode($arr,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Output:-

```
{"lat":-33.661853351608244}
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response.   If I dont have the ini_set function its returning the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this inconsistency of JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK with phone numbers starting with a zero. I solved the problem by encapsulating the phone number, between two empty chains like this:

```
$pre_tel = "0606060606";
$tel = " ".$pre_tel." ";
```